# Java EE: Strange behavior when implement logging

Tags: java, logging, jakarta-ee

I use `java.util.logging`, and I put the log inside a application managed bean, since I think there should be just one logger for the entire application.

```
@ManagedBean(name="logging")  
@ApplicationScoped
public class Logging {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Logger.class.getName());
    private static FileHandler fh = null;

    public Logging() {
        try{
            fh = new FileHandler("DMBackingBean");
        }catch(IOException ignore){}
        logger.addHandler(fh);
        logger.setLevel(Level.ALL);
    }

    public Logger getLogger(){
        return logger;
    }
}
```

Here is the strange behavior I run into. When I run the program the first time, I log `AAA` inside `DMBackingBean`. Then I **redeploy** the application (new session), now I saw another log file is created, `DMBackingBean.1` with content of `AAA`. The contain of `DMBackingBean` is now
`AAA`
`AAA`

Two question: Is it standard to put the logging inside an application scoped bean? Is there a way for me to have all the logs append into one file, instead of every time I redeploy (new session), a new log file is created?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it standard to put the logging inside an application scoped bean?

IMO, it's more typical to create a hierarchy of loggers so that you can activate and control logging in a fine grained manner (e.g. configuring `com.acme.Foo` to log at the ERROR level while configuring the logging of `com.acme.bar.BAR` at the DEBUG level).

> Is there a way for me to have all the logs append into one file, instead of every time I redeploy (new session), a new log file is created?

It looks like you need to create an appending file handler:

```
try { 
    // Create an appending file handler
    boolean append = true; 
    FileHandler handler = new FileHandler("my.log", append); 
    ...
}
```

#### References

- [JavaTM Logging Overview](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/util/logging/overview.html)

Comment: I try `FileHandler handler = new FileHandler("my.log", true)`, but it still creating new log file every time I rerun the application. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

You need to undo your logging when the bean is undeployed.  Otherwise you will add a new one everytime you redeploy.

Comment: how can I undo the log? can u be a bit more specific?

Comment: You call "addHandler(...)".  When that deployment goes away, you need to call the opposite method too.  Consider it similar to close().